# How to run ctr or crictl commands when k3s in rootless mode

Tags: k3s, containerd, rootless

I'm using k3s cluster in rootless-mode. When i try to run some ctr or crictl commands i get there errors:

```
[user@k3s-user-ol images]$ ctr image ls
ctr: failed to dial "/run/k3s/containerd/containerd.sock": context deadline exceeded

[user@k3s-user-ol images]$ crictl images
FATA[0002] connect: connect endpoint 'unix:///run/k3s/containerd/containerd.sock', make sure you are running as root and the endpoint has been started: context deadline exceeded
```

Images are pulled from my Nexus repository correctly. But how can i export\import images manually by user?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that k3s uses a hard-coded path to the `containerd` socket as `/run/k3s/containerd/containerd.sock`. [Reference](https://github.dev/k3s-io/k3s/blob/master/cmd/server/main.go)

In rootless mode, the `containerd` is not creating the `containerd.sock` file, because it has no permission to write at `/run`.

I was unable to find a way to change it, then I got it working with the following:

```
mkdir -pv ~/.rancher/run-k3s
sudo ln -sv ~/.rancher/run-k3s /run/k3s/
systemctl --user restart k3s-rootless
```

I can see 2 issues here:

- Before each `k3s-rootless` starts, I have to delete the `~/.rancher/run-k3s/containerd` folder, otherwise it fails to connect to the `containerd.sock`. I don't know why.
- `/run` is an in-memory folder, which means the link will be gone after the host reboot.

Hope it helps.